# How to avoid unwanted slashes in json while inserting into mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, npm, sails.js

How to avoid unwanted slashes in json while inserting into mongodb...

```
"flow" : "{\"name\":\"flowname test1\",\"id\":\"55c2088ca03f0d9a3db05863\",\"url\":\"google.com\",\"success msg\":\"success\"}",
```

Comment: Don't JSON.stringify() the object before setting it. Then it will just save as an object. You likely have something like that in your code. Either that or you are reading a string containing JSON from somwhere. Call `JSON.parse(string)` and it becomes an object.